# Query Firebase for selected values in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a chat app in Swift where I am using Firebase. In my Firebase database, I have an object called `members`. From that `members`, I only want data which has a particular key name.

My structure:

[image]

So from `members`, I only want data which has `anuj` as the key.

Code:

```
 refMembers.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: true, childKey: "anuj").observe(.value, with: { (snap) in

            Logger.sharedInstance.log(whatToPrint: snap.childrenCount as AnyObject)
           *******This crashes my app*******
        })
```

Code

```
    refMembers.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { (snap) in
                Logger.sharedInstance.log(whatToPrint: snap.childrenCount as AnyObject)

******* here i get no data*******
            })
```

Comment: `refMembers.queryOrderedByChild("anuj").queryEqualToValue("true")`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 this returns a null snapshot

Comment: what is refmember???  can u post whole path?

Comment: let refMembers = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("members/")

Comment: `refMembers.queryOrderedByChild("anuj").queryEqual(toValue:tr‌​ue)` then this should work i think

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
refMembers.orderByChild("anuj").equalTo(true).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key)
})
```

Read more [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByChild)